# SwiftUI: Updating a View to include a Custom Subview based on a user action is a separate view

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

so I am trying to have a view update to display a custom view based on a user selection from another view. This is a simple task app project I started to get a better understanding of SwiftUI and have hit my first major roadblock. The custom view is generated from a Tag object from Core Data, so it would be this information that is passed from View 2 to View 1.

I've marked where the update would take place as well as where the action is performed with TODOs. Hopefully I did a good job at explaining what I am hoping to accomplish, nothing I have tried seems to work. I am sure it's something simple but the solution is evading me.

**View 1**: View that needs to be updated when user returns

[image: View 1]

**View 2**: View where selection is made

[image: View 2]

**The View that needs to be updated and its ViewModel.**

```
struct AddTaskView: View {
    
    //MARK: Variables
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var coreDataHandler
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject var viewModel = AddTaskViewModel()
    @StateObject var taskListViewModel = TaskListViewModel()
    
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @State private var info: String = ""
    @State private var dueDate = Date()

    var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Add a New Task")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                //MARK: Task.title Field
                TextField("Task", text: $title)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    //TODO: Update to a specific color
                    .background(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                //MARK: Task.tag Field
                HStack {
                    Text("Tag")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    //TODO: UPDATE TO DISPLAY TAG IF SELECTED OTHERWISE DISPLAY ADDTAGBUTTONVIEW
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TagListView(),
                        label: {
                            AddTagButtonView()
                        }
                    )
                    .accentColor(.black)
                }
                
                //MARK: Task.info Field
                TextEditor(text: $info)
                    
                    .frame(width: screenWidth - 40, height: screenHeight/4, alignment: .center)
                    .autocapitalization(.sentences)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 0.5)
                    )
                
                
                //MARK: Task.dateDue Field
                DatePicker(
                    "Due Date",
                    selection: $dueDate,
                    in: Date()...
                )
                .accentColor(.black)
                .font(.headline)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.addTask(taskTitle: title, taskInfo: info, taskDueDate: dueDate)
                    //Dismiss View if successful
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Task")
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 60)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                })
                
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

```
final class AddTaskViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    var coreDataHandler = CoreDataHandler.shared
    
    @Published var tag : Tag?
    
    func addTask(taskTitle: String, taskInfo: String, taskDueDate: Date) {
        let newTask = Task(context: coreDataHandler.container.viewContext)
        
        newTask.title = taskTitle
        newTask.info = taskInfo
        newTask.dateCreated = Date()
        newTask.dateDue = taskDueDate
        newTask.completed = false
        newTask.archived = false
        
        coreDataHandler.save()
    }
}
```

**The View where the selection is made and its ViewModel**

```
struct TagListView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Tag.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Tag.title, ascending: true)]) var tagList : FetchedResults<Tag>
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = TagListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Create a Tag")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: CreateTagView(),
                    label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                    })
            }
            
            Divider()
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                if tagList.count != 0 {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(tagList, id: \.self) { tag in
                            let tagColour = Color(red: tag.colourR, green: tag.colourG, blue: tag.colourB, opacity: tag.colourA)
                            Button {

                                //TODO: UPDATE ADDTASKVIEW TO DISPLAY THE SELECTED TAG

                                //Dismiss view
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            } label: {
                                TagView(title: tag.title ?? "Tag", color: tagColour, darkText: false)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Add your first tag.")
                }
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

```
final class TagListViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
}
```

Comment: using `ObservableObject` is a generally good idea to pass data around 
the different views. However sometimes a simple binding can also be useful. This answer maybe relevant to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503249/present-alert-on-previous-screen-swiftui/69503524#69503524

Comment: I guess the confusing part is how that all works when the item being referenced is a CoreData entity whose info populates the custom view.